# Azur Key Vault - CORS Error after using Azure KeyVault in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, cors, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to get value from Azure Key Vault. It's working well in localhost but when we deploy to Azure App Service. it shows CORS Error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxxxxx.azure-api.net/xxxxxx/api/xxx/xxxx' from origin 'https://xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I'm using below code in my .Net Core Web API:

```
const string secretName = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
var kvUri = $"https://xxxxxxxx.vault.azure.net";
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
var secret = client.GetSecretAsync(secretName).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Value;
conString = secret.Value;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with Key Vault. Have you configured CORS rules on your API to allow XHR requests from your App Service?

Comment: Isn't azure-api.net an API Management URL? Like Gaurav said, this isn't about Key Vault. You need a CORS policy in API Management to allow the request from your front-end.

Comment: Please refer this https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/how-to-troubleshoot-cors-error-in-azure-api-management-service/ba-p/2241695  to solve the issue.

Comment: I have already implemented CORS for API and it's working fine without KeyVault perfectly. but when I add the KeyVault it shows CORS error.

Comment: Can you confirm if your key vault code is working properly and is not throwing an error?

Answer (score 1):

CORS isn't permitted for Key Vault at this time because it's not designed to be used by browsers.  I spoke with the KV product team about this a good while back and created a UserVoice submission for this feature a few years ago:  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/906355-azure-key-vault/suggestions/34753195-enable-cors-for-key-vault

Answer (score 0):

Were you logged in to Azure when you tested this application locally?
Also for app service to access key vault you would need some authentication mechanism
like service principal or managed Identity.

You can check this link for your reference:
[Access key vault from app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-dotnet/keyvault-msi-appservice-sample/)